# Border color opacity acts differently on table rows

Tags: html, css

I'm using opacity parametr for `rgba` color and only last-child element provides the color i want, every other border displays different color. You can even test it by colorpicker in devtools.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.content > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: white;
}
.content > table > tbody > tr.topic {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(16, 151, 255, 0.41);

}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="topic">
              <td class="topic-title">
                <i class="topic-icon"></i>
                Title
              </td>
              <td class="topic-replies">
                <i class="replies-icon"></i>
                15
              </td>
              <td class="topic-author">
                Name
              </td>
              <td class="topic-timestamp">
                <time>20m.</time>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="topic">
              <td class="topic-title">
                <i class="topic-icon"></i>
                Title
              </td>
              <td class="topic-replies">
                <i class="replies-icon"></i>
                15
              </td>
              <td class="topic-author">
                Name
              </td>
              <td class="topic-timestamp">
                <time>20m.</time>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="topic">
              <td class="topic-title">
                <i class="topic-icon"></i>
                Title
              </td>
              <td class="topic-replies">
                <i class="replies-icon"></i>
                15
              </td>
              <td class="topic-author">
                Name
              </td>
              <td class="topic-timestamp">
                <time>20m.</time>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? [This is what I see in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COceV.png) - all three borders look the same to me?

Comment: It looks like a bug in `-webkit-` browsers.

Comment: @Frits Chrome 59.0.3071.115

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me a bug in chrome browser.

An alternate approach would be to use `background-image` instead of `border-bottom`.

We can use [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) to achieve the same effect.

```
.content > table > tbody > tr.topic {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(16, 151, 255, 0.41), rgba(16, 151, 255, 0.41));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-size: 100% 1px;
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.content > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: white;
}
.content > table > tbody > tr.topic {
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(16, 151, 255, 0.41), rgba(16, 151, 255, 0.41));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: 100% 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="topic">
        <td class="topic-title">
          <i class="topic-icon"></i>
          Title
        </td>
        <td class="topic-replies">
          <i class="replies-icon"></i>
          15
        </td>
        <td class="topic-author">
          Name
        </td>
        <td class="topic-timestamp">
          <time>20m.</time>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="topic">
        <td class="topic-title">
          <i class="topic-icon"></i>
          Title
        </td>
        <td class="topic-replies">
          <i class="replies-icon"></i>
          15
        </td>
        <td class="topic-author">
          Name
        </td>
        <td class="topic-timestamp">
          <time>20m.</time>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="topic">
        <td class="topic-title">
          <i class="topic-icon"></i>
          Title
        </td>
        <td class="topic-replies">
          <i class="replies-icon"></i>
          15
        </td>
        <td class="topic-author">
          Name
        </td>
        <td class="topic-timestamp">
          <time>20m.</time>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wow pretty much seems like webkit having issues displaying that border properly.

You can try [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) on those rows instead:

```
.content > table > tbody > tr.topic {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(16, 151, 255, 0.41);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=312121)

Your choice is to either leave the alpha settings as they are since other browsers should be rendering it correctly and await the fix or to just use rgb values for the time being.

Or as ~Laszlo has suggested, use a box-shadow.

Answer (score -3):

```
<th>Title <i class="sort-by" data-sort-type="-1"></i></th>


/*sorting Icons*/
th i.sort-by { 
    padding-right: 18px;
    position: relative;
        cursor:pointer;
}
th i.sort-by:before,
th i.sort-by:after {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
th i.sort-by[data-sort-type="0"]:before {
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
th i.sort-by[data-sort-type="1"]:before {
    border-bottom-color: #03a9f4;
        margin-top: -9px;
}
th i.sort-by[data-sort-type="-1"]:before {
    border-bottom-color: #999;
        margin-top: -9px;
}

th i.sort-by:after {
    border-top-color: #999;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
th i.sort-by[data-sort-type="-1"]:after {
    border-top-color: #03a9f4;
        margin-top: 1px;

}


$('i.sort-by').click(function(){
              //  alert($(this).attr("data-sort-type"));
              if($(this).attr("data-sort-type") == 0){
                  $(this).attr("data-sort-type", 1);
              }
              else if($(this).attr("data-sort-type") == 1){
                  $(this).attr("data-sort-type", -1);
              }
              else{
                  $(this).attr("data-sort-type", 0);
              }     
            });
```

Comment: But the asker *wants* semitransparent borders!